# group by first letter alphabetically

Tags: php, mysqli

With the following script, values ​​are entered alphabetically sorted under the capital letter.
However, I can't get `$author` into the while statement so it appears with 'title'.

I want the last html part included in the while statement. But no matter what I try, it doesn't work
What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select `link`, `titel`, `author` from `books` where `id`=? order by `titel`asc ")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($link, $titel, $author);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $titel = mb_strimwidth("$titel", 0, 30, "...");
        $letter = substr($titel, 0, 1);
        $res[$letter][] = $titel;

    }
    foreach ($res as $key => $val) {
        ?>
        <div class="<?php $letter; ?>"></div>
        <?php

        echo $key; //shows capital letter
        foreach ($val as $reqvals) {
            echo $reqvals; //shows 'titel'
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <a href="#se_annonce<?php echo $link; ?>" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="author">By <?php $author; ?></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php

    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the while loop is finished executing, there are no `$link`s or `$author`s; they have not been saved anywhere.

One option would be to save them in the `$res` array. Perhaps something like:

```
$res[$letter][] = [$titel, $author, $link];
```

The "last html part" could be created in the `foreach($val as $reqvals)` (remembering of course that `$reqvals` is a list) because it would have access to the "whole row".

Comment: When I do, and run a check  with print_r($res);, I get this:
```
Array
(
    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Da himmelen kom nærmere
                    [1] => Brian Patrick McGuire
                    [2] => 239
                )

        )

)
```
so the values ​​are retrieved. But I can't get them loaded on the page: Where the title should be is simply says "array". Please help.

Comment: Remember, here `foreach ($val as $reqvals)` $reqvals is now an array, so title is in `$reqvals[0]`.

Comment: Thanks DinoCoderSaurus. Now I've got it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside to [DinoCoderSaurus'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60466344/3536236) answer, you have

> ```
>  <div class="author">By <?php $author; ?></div>
> ```

What you probably want is:

```
<div class="author">By <?php print $author; ?></div>
```

or

```
<div class="author">By <?=$author;?></div>
```

Yes, you need to instruct PHP to print the variable to the screen.

See also:

```
  <div class="<?php print $letter; ?>"></div>
```